# collection value comparsion

Tags: c#

I have and want to compare two IDictionary collection for sepecific key value.
E.g. IDictionary col1  and E.g. IDictionary col2.

i am looping all items from both the collection and finally using this "Equals" to compare key values from both the collection -

```
if(col1.Values[key2].Equals(col2.Values[key2])) 
{

}
```

But "Equals" will compare object reference, so it is right way to do or any alternative solution ?

Comment: If `Equals` compares the reference depends on whether it was overriden in the class. So what type are the values in your dictionaries?

Comment: The title of this post has nothing to do with the question being asked

Comment: key is string and value is object.

Comment: If value is and object do Col1 and Col2 always contains the same underlying type e.g. are you sure you are never comparing a string with an int.

Comment: since value is object, for same key in both the collection, value would be of same type (string or int or any thing).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. override Equals (and GetHashCode) on the type that represents your values
2. don't compare using equals but your own function
3. implement a comparer and use this
   and a couple more

In this case I would use 2) if you don't need to compare those values elsewhere if you do than use 1

Remarks to 1:)

you will need on your ValueType (MyValue):

```
class MyValue
{
   // ...
   public override GetHashCode()
   {
      return this.Property1.GetHashCode();
      // if you want to compare more properties hash them all and use some function (for example ^)
      // to "add" the values
   }

   public override Equals(obj o)
   {
      if (ReferenceEquals(null, o)) return false;
      if (ReferenceEquals(this, o)) return true;
      if (o.GetType() != typeof (MyValue)) return false;
      var v2 = o as MyValue;
      return Equals(v2.Property1, this.Property1);
      // if you want to compare more than one property use && and Equals on them all
   }
}
```

Remarks to 2:)
instead of

```
if(col1.Values[key2].Equals(col2.Values[key2]))
```

use some thing like this

```
bool CompareTwoValues(MyValue v1, MyValue v2)
{
   if(!Equals(v1.Property1, v2.Property1)) return false;
   // ... whatever you have to compare based on the values
   return true;
}
```

with

```
if (CompareTwoValues(col1.Values[key2], col2.Values[key2])
{
  // ....
}
```

PS: Equals and GetHashCode can be (very) tricke sometimes - please search a bit an make sure that GetHashCode is implemented correctly. Also better only compare immutable values on your classes this way.